# JSF Primefaces outputLabel get value is null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have button on my view. When I click it there is an action handler where I'm getting view root from faces context and then I get form. Then I loop through facets and children of the form and I look for OutputLabel instances. When I get it I'm trying to getValue from it. But it's always null, but on rendered page there is value. OutputLabel (p:outputLabel) is placed in composite component...
What do I wrong? Some ideas?

**// EDIT**

```
public void buttonHandler(){
   FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   UIForm form = facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("formId");
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
   collectLabels(form, list);
}

public void collectLabels(UIComponent component, List<String> list){
   Iterator<UIComponent> iterator = component.getFacetsAndChildren();

   while(iterator.hasNext()){
      UIComponent child = iterator.next();
      collectLabels(child, list);
   }

   if(component instanceof OutputLabel){
      list.add(((OutputLabel)component).getValue());
   } 
}
```

I'm not at work now. So I don't remember my composite component code now. But it contains `<p:outputLabel for="#{cc.attr.id}" value="#{cc.attr.labelValue}" />`

Comment: Please create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do you really get the label but not it's value? I guess you already fail on getting the label.

Comment: I got info the condition with label. I also checked its ID ans its pointing to my label.